# How to convert PIL image file into string in python3.4?

Tags: image, python-imaging-library, python-3.4

I have been trying to read a jpeg file using PIL in python 3.4. I need to save this file into string format. Although some options are provided on this site but I have tried a few but it is not working. Following is my code snippet which i have found on this site only:-

```
from io import StringIO

fp = Image.open("images/login.jpg")
output = StringIO()
fp.save(output, format="JPEG")
contents = output.getvalue()
output.close()
```

But i am facing the following error :-

TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'

Could you please suggest what I have done wrong and how to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

In python 3 you should use a [BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO),
whereas as read in  python docs:

> StringIO is a native in-memory **unicode** container

.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint.  I Actually have a found a different way of reading the image file and storing in string object. Here is the code. Please let me know if there is any disadvantage of this.... imgText = open("images/login.jpg", 'rb')
            imgTextStr = imgText.read()
            imgText.close()

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the hint. I Actually have a found a different way of reading the image file and storing in string object in python2.x . Here is the code. Please let me know if there is any disadvantage of using this.

```
imgText = open("images/login.jpg", 'rb') 
imgTextStr = imgText.read() 
imgText.close()
```